# How to configure VirtualHost for a Sinatra App with Passenger?

Tags: sinatra, passenger, rack, vhosts

I run a Rails app on Passenger and it all works like it should.

I want to add a Sinatra app to run as a Rack application with Passenger, but I get a routing error.

My VirtualHosts File looks like:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.domain1.com
  DocumentRoot /home/user1/vhosts/project1/public
  ErrorLog     /home/user1/vhosts/project1/log/httpd_error_log
  CustomLog    /home/user1/vhosts/project1/log/httpd_access_log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.sub.domain2.com
  DocumentRoot /home/user2/vhosts/sinatra_app/lib/public
  ErrorLog     /home/user2/vhosts/sinatra_app/lib/log/httpd_error_log
  CustomLog    /home/user2/vhosts/sinatra_app/lib/log/httpd_access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My Sinatra app is really simple; I have a route called `get "/do_something" do ....` with no public files. it only responds with some JSON.

How can I make it do requests like `www.sub.domain2.com/do_something`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems OK,are the priviledges set correctly?

Comment: problem solved, my settings were correct, i upgraded passenger to latest version and all works like it should :)

thanks for help!